# Create new gstreamer plugin on windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

I started to read about building a new plugin and found this guide:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/pwg/html/

I noticed that this guide is for linux, my question is if there is another guide for windows? or it's the same..

I also found this template (for windows):

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-template/tree/gst-plugin/src

but it I can't compile it, I get build errors- on Visual Studio.

so my questios is-

1. if there is some kind of working template which I could start working on (on windows..)
2. how to make the new plugin after the code will be compiled, how the "gst-launch" will recognize it?

I will be happy for some kick starter on that issue.

thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the some build issues.